# Whenever CRON tab doesn't work on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, cron, whenever

I am trying to set up CRON jobs on Amazon EC2 with using the **Whenever** gem.
In the `schedule.rb` is following:

```
 set :output, "/home/my_deploy_name/my_deploy_name/current/log/cron_log.log"

 every 2.minutes do
   puts "It's working !!!"
 end
```

and in the `deploy.rb` this:

```
...
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
after 'deploy:create_symlink', 'whenever:update_crontab'
after 'deploy:rollback', 'whenever:update_crontab'
```

When I deploy this code to EC2 and check `crontab -l`, the output is:

```
no crontab for ubuntu
```

When I run `crontab -e`, the file is not edited.

What is wrong here? What the CRON job doesn't run on EC2 every 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options to try:

1) Log into the server and run:

`bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`

and check your crontab.

2) You don't need to set the `before` and `after` callbacks. The capistrano recipe does that for you:

https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance(:must_exist).load do
  # Write the new cron jobs near the end.
  before "deploy:finalize_update", "whenever:update_crontab"
  # If anything goes wrong, undo.
  after "deploy:rollback", "whenever:update_crontab"
end
```

Comment: I am using `gem 'whenever', :require => false`, also updated the **recipes** there, but still **no crontab for ubuntu**.

Comment: What version of `whenever` are you using?

Comment: I mean, when I just deploy a code to EC2 with capistrano, the cron jobs should automatically work on EC2 itself? There is not needed to activate it or so? On localhost I see the output for **crontab -l**, but not on EC2.

Comment: The last one - `0.8.4`

Comment: Updated my answer. You should try doing it manually. It's possible you're getting an error and can only be seen while logged into your EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you. When I run `whenever --update-crontab`, I will get error: `Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.2.44`

Comment: Sorry, forgot `bundle exec`. Edited my answer.